# SQLite выбивает работу WebSocket

Tags: python, sqlite, websocket

День добрый. берутся данные через WebSocket с биржи, каждую запись нужно вносить в БД SQLite3. Однако доходя до команды "cursor.execute" код крашится.

Выдавая "**WebSocket Inverse Perp(Auth) encountered error: unrecognized token: "25T18**"

```
from time import sleep
from pybit import inverse_perpetual
import sqlite3

ws_inverseP = inverse_perpetual.WebSocket(
    test=True,
    ping_interval=30,
    ping_timeout=10,
    domain="bybit"
)


def handle_message(msg):
    order = msg['data']

    for item in range(len(order)):
        if order[item]['side'] == 'Buy':

            connect = sqlite3.connect('db/tradeflow.sqlite')
            cursor = connect.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Buy(price, volume, timestamp) "
                           f"VALUES({order[item]['price']}, {order[item]['size']}, {order[item]['timestamp']})")
            connect.commit()
            connect.close()


ws_inverseP.trade_stream(handle_message, "BTCUSD")

while True:
    sleep(1)
```

файл sqlite - tradeflow.sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE Buy (
    [index]   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
    price     DOUBLE,
    volume    DOUBLE,
    timestamp STRING
);
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). В текущем виде непонятно как одно связанно с другим и в каком именно месте возникает ошибка

Comment: Исправил вопрос, дабы не выкладывать тут гору кода, сделал короткий вариант, суть осталась таже, он так же не работает и крашится на операции cursor.execute

Answer (score 1):

Методом проб и ошибок, удалась завести рабочий вариант получения данных и запись их в базу.

```
import sqlite3
from time import sleep

from pybit import inverse_perpetual

ws_inverseP = inverse_perpetual.WebSocket(
    test=True,
    ping_interval=30,
    ping_timeout=10,
    domain="bybit"
)


def handle_message(msg):
    order = msg['data']
    data = (order[0]['price'], order[0]['size'], order[0]['timestamp'], order[0]['side'])

    connect = sqlite3.connect('db/tradeflow.sqlite')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO trades VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (data,))
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()


ws_inverseP.trade_stream(handle_message, "BTCUSD")

while True:
    sleep(1)
```